# Problems with removeClass()

Tags: html, jquery

On the front-end I'm asking the user 2 questions, the first one visible, the second will be visible depending on the firs answer. But somehow my removeClass is not working as expected (not working at all)

```
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 md-form">
                            <label for="savingcontratos">Cancelamento de Contratos?</label>
                            <select class="mdb-select md-form" id="savingcontratos" searchable="Pesquisar">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="0">Sim</option>
                                <option value="1">Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                       <div class="form-group col-md-4 md-form invisible" id="divcontratos">
                            <label for="txtcontratos">Insira os contratos envolvidos</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcontratos" value="0">
                        </div>
```

And the functions I'm using are:

```
$('#savingfinanceiro').on('change',function () {
   var component = $("#divfinanceiro");
   makevisible($('#savingfinanceiro').val(), component);
});

 function makevisible(value,component){    
    if (value === "0"){
            component.removeClass("invisible");
    }
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. So do you mean the class is not removed? Or there's some other problem? Have you checked for sure that `#divfinanceiro` matches an element in the DOM?

Comment: In the provided HTML, there is no `savingfinanceiro` nor `divfinanceiro`

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out in the comments `#savingfinanceiro` and `#divfinanceiro` do not exist in your html. You must have overlooked that. In the following snippet I have fixed that. There, `#savingfinanceiro`, from the `<select>`, was changed to `#savingcontratos` and `var component = $("#divfinanceiro");`, the 'to-hide' `<div>` was changed to `var component = $("#divcontratos");`. After applying these changes your code should work as expected.

```js
$('#savingcontratos').on('change', function() {
  var component = $("#divcontratos");
  makevisible($('#savingcontratos').val(), component);
});

function makevisible(value, component) {
  if (value === "0") {
    component.removeClass("invisible");
  } else {
    component.addClass("invisible");
  }
}
```

```css
.invisible {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 md-form">
  <label for="savingcontratos">Cancelamento de Contratos?</label>
  <select class="mdb-select md-form" id="savingcontratos" searchable="Pesquisar">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">Sim</option>
    <option value="1">Não</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 md-form invisible" id="divcontratos">
  <label for="txtcontratos">Insira os contratos envolvidos</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcontratos" value="0">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!